# google charts timeline - get text on row mouse click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, google-visualization

i want to take out 'text value' on mouse click on anywhere on the row/svg image ,for i.e. in the below image if i click anywhere on 2nd blue highlighted row, then i should be able to get the text 'Adams' as alert. I tried to iterate thru svg elements but svg elements are created horizontally rather then vertically

[image: example]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use the `'select'` [event](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline#events), to determine the value selected

when the `'select'` event fires, check `chart.getSelection()`

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function () {
  selection = chart.getSelection();
  if (selection.length > 0) {
    console.log(dataTable.getValue(selection[0].row, 0));
  }
});
```

[`getSelection`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline#methods) returns an array of the selected rows,
Timeline charts only allow one row to be selected at a time,
so the selection will always be in the first element
`chart.getSelection()[0]`

each element in the array will have properties for `row` and `column`
(`column` will always be `null` for a Timeline chart)

once you have the `row`, you can use [`getValue`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable_getValue) on the DataTable
`dataTable.getValue(selection[0].row, 0)`

`getValue` takes two arguments, `rowIndex` and `columnIndex`

use `0` to get the value of the first column

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'President' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
    dataTable.addRows([
      [ 'Washington', new Date(1789, 3, 30), new Date(1797, 2, 4) ],
      [ 'Adams',      new Date(1797, 2, 4),  new Date(1801, 2, 4) ],
      [ 'Jefferson',  new Date(1801, 2, 4),  new Date(1809, 2, 4) ]]);

    var container = document.getElementById('timeline');
    var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);

    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function () {
      selection = chart.getSelection();
      if (selection.length > 0) {
        console.log(dataTable.getValue(selection[0].row, 0));
      }
    });

    chart.draw(dataTable);
  },
  packages: ['timeline']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="timeline"></div>
```

**EDIT**

to capture the click anywhere on the row, outside the colored bar,
use the `'ready'` event to find the svg elements and add a listener

the elements will have an `x` attribute of zero (`0`)
and a `fill` attribute other than `'none'`

since the number of elements will match the number of rows,
we can use the index of the element, amongst its peers, to find the value

see following working snippet,
both the `'select'` and `'click'` events are used to find the value clicked

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'President' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
    dataTable.addRows([
      [ 'Washington', new Date(1789, 3, 30), new Date(1797, 2, 4) ],
      [ 'Adams',      new Date(1797, 2, 4),  new Date(1801, 2, 4) ],
      [ 'Jefferson',  new Date(1801, 2, 4),  new Date(1809, 2, 4) ]]);

    var container = document.getElementById('timeline');
    var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);

    var saveRows = [];
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
      chartRows = container.getElementsByTagName('rect');
      Array.prototype.forEach.call(chartRows, function(row) {
        if ((parseInt(row.getAttribute('x')) === 0) && (row.getAttribute('fill') !== 'none')) {
          saveRows.push(row);
          row.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            for (var i = 0; i < saveRows.length; i++) {
              if (e.target === saveRows[i]) {
                getRowLabel(i);
                break;
              }
            }
          }, false);
        }
      });
    });

    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function () {
      selection = chart.getSelection();
      if (selection.length > 0) {
        getRowLabel(selection[0].row);
      }
    });

    function getRowLabel(index) {
      console.log(dataTable.getValue(index, 0));
    }

    chart.draw(dataTable);
  },
  packages: ['timeline']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="timeline"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts :), But this is not what i was asking for,  if you carefully read the problem statement - i have asked for ''if i click anywhere on 2nd blue highlighted row'', so i should get the Text value if i click anywhere on the row not just only on the item click on timeline.

Comment: the _2nd blue highlighted row_ threw me off, I only see one blue row. anyway, see __EDIT__ to above answer to capture click anywhere on row...