# How to get data point x/y values when Google Visualisation line chart data point clicked

Tags: google-visualization

I am using Google Visualisation to draw a line chart with a single line. The horizontal axis represents dates and the vertical axis represents a count of events on each date.

When a user clicks on a data point on the line, I need to pass the date associated with the data point to a report script that prints details of each event.

I've added a listener function to the chart and it does receive notice that a data point was clicked but how do I get the date associated with the data point?

Comment: when the select event fires, use the `getSelection` [method](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#methods) to determine the data table row and column that was selected. - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38698550/5090771) is an example...

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly.